# Is IEnumerable.Max() the fastest way?

Tags: c#, performance, ienumerable

I am developing a part of a software, where I have a list (`List<Sample>` at the moment) of samples like the following:

```
public class Sample
{
    //...
    public double ValueChannel1 { get; set; }
    public double ValueChannel2 { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

These lists have between ~100 and several thousands of these samples and there are around 100k samples per second.
Now I need to find the maximum and minimum value out of each of these lists, which I do the following way at the moment:

```
var Ch1Max = task.Samples.Max<Sample>(s => s.ValueChannel1);
var Ch1Min = task.Samples.Min<Sample>(s => s.ValueChannel1);
var Ch2Max = task.Samples.Max<Sample>(s => s.ValueChannel2);
var Ch2Min = task.Samples.Min<Sample>(s => s.ValueChannel2);
```

To no surprise this is not very fast, so I was asking myself if there is something faster to do that, but I could not think of or find one?

**Does someone know a faster way to do this?**
Maybe there is a way to find min and max with "one loop" instead of one for min and one for max?

**Edit:**
I profiled the current code with the following results:
731 tasks each containing one of these lists needed 845ms to process and 95% of that where the min/max searching.
I have no specific "target time", but as this runs all the time in my app (as it is capturing measurement data) it should cause as little CPU utlization as possible, to keep the hardware requirements as low as possible...

**Best solution found:**
In the end I choose the soltuion from Tim, as it was even a little faster then Konrad ones:
Tim's solution caused a speed-up of ~53% and Konrads's "only" ~43%.

**Final solution (for now):**

```
double Ch1Max = Double.MinValue, Ch1Min = Double.MaxValue;
double Ch2Max = Double.MinValue, Ch2Min = Double.MaxValue;

var samples = task.Samples.ToArray();
int count = samples.Length;
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
{
    var valueChannel1 = samples[i].ValueChannel1; // get only once => faster
    if (valueChannel1 > Ch1Max) Ch1Max = valueChannel1;
    if (valueChannel1 < Ch1Min) Ch1Min = valueChannel1;

    var valueChannel2 = samples[i].ValueChannel2;
    if (valueChannel2 > Ch2Max) Ch2Max = valueChannel2;
    if (valueChannel2 < Ch2Min) Ch2Min = valueChannel2;
}
```

This sums up to a speed up of ~70% compared to my initial solution...

Comment: How slow is "not very fast"? Have you measured it?

Comment: Any more specifics on time taken/target time?

Comment: There is a way to find them in one loop. Loop through them and keep track of the minimum and maximum value.

Comment: No, having one loop for min and one for max is not the fastest way. But writing min/max loops is a programming execise for the first weeks, why don't you write it yourself?

Comment: @novoigt: I am currently trying it with "my own loop", but I though the .NET team can do it better then I can...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a single loop:

```
double Ch1Max = double.MinValue;
double Ch1Min = double.MaxValue;
double Ch2Max = double.MinValue;
double Ch2Min = double.MaxValue;
foreach(Sample s in samples)
{
    if(s.ValueChannel1 > Ch1Max) Ch1Max = s.ValueChannel1;
    if(s.ValueChannel1 < Ch1Min) Ch1Min = s.ValueChannel1;
    if(s.ValueChannel2 > Ch2Max) Ch2Max = s.ValueChannel2;
    if(s.ValueChannel2 < Ch2Min) Ch2Min = s.ValueChannel2;
}
```

Comment: usually `for` faster, but it all depends on how it is all compiled

Comment: `usually` is not true. That was valid in .NET 1.1. http://lj.rossia.org/users/steinkrauz/300537.html So meanwhile a `foreach` is compiled as a `for` (if possible).

Comment: Thanks for that input - how stupid of me, not to think of that simple x4 speed-up - I just did not had the idea to combine all 4 in one loop...

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Exactly, if possible, so how i say in second part of my comment all depends on the generated IL code

Comment: @Grundy: Yes, but the first part suggests that `usually for is faster` which is not true (anymore). People who don't know how it is compiled could think that they  should avoid `foreach` in general.

Comment: @TimSchmelter roger! :-)

Comment: I am back to this code in my current "performance round" and did try using `for` instead of `foreach` this time => 13.65% faster in this case...

Comment: @chrfin: you need to show how you've measured the time since i don't believe that the `foreach` is the bottleneck. I suspect that you have called the `foreach` many times which is pointless. Normally it's much more important how often the loop _loops_, so how large the collection is.

Answer (score 8):

If you have control over your `List<Sample>` object (I mean you don't get it from a third party code etc.), you could enwrap it in your own class, which would keep track of maximum and minimum values on the fly, as you're adding elements into it.

All it would take is just looking up whether the new `Sample` does not "set the new record" and accordingly adjust your cached maximum / minimum values if so.

That approach would be very efficient if the list is forward-only, eg. you're not removing elements from the list.

**EDIT:**

Here's a sample implementation (it's bit of a "proof of concept", there's surely lots of space for improvement):

```
public class Sample
{
    public double ValueChannel1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double ValueChannel2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    // etc.
}

public class SampleList
{
    /* that's the list we're enwrapping. 
     * SampleList could also be inherited from List<Sample>, but in general this approach is less recommended -
     * read up on "composition over inheritance". */
    private List<Sample> _samples = new List<Sample>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Caches the lowest known value of ValueChannel1 property
    /// </summary>
    public double? ValueChannel1Minimum // it's a nullable double, because while the list is still empty, minimums and maximums have no value yet
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public double? ValueChannel1Maximum { get; private set; }
    public double? ValueChannel2Minimum { get; private set; } 
    public double? ValueChannel2Maximum { get; private set; }

    public void Add(Sample sample)
    {
        if (sample == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("sample");
        }
        // have you beat the record?
        if (sample.ValueChannel1 <= (ValueChannel1Minimum ?? double.MaxValue))
        {                
            // note: the essence of the trick with ?? operator is: if there's no minimum set yet, pretend the minimum to be the biggest value there is.
            // practically speaking, it ensures that the first element added to the list
            // sets the new minimum, whatever value that element had.
            ValueChannel1Minimum = sample.ValueChannel1;
        }
        if (sample.ValueChannel1 >= (ValueChannel1Maximum ?? double.MinValue))
        {
            ValueChannel1Maximum = sample.ValueChannel1;
        }

        // etc. for other properties

        _samples.Add(sample);
    }

    public List<Sample> ToList()
    {
        return _samples;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always implement the min/max logic yourself. It should be easy using the `Aggregate` extension method:

```
Pair<Sample, Sample> minMax = task.Samples.Aggregate(
  new Pair<Sample, Sample> {
    First = new Sample { ValueChannel1 = double.MaxValue, ValueChannel2 = double.MaxValue },
    Second = new Sample { ValueChannel1 = double.MinValue, ValueChannel2 = double.MinValue }
  },
  (minmax, sample) => {
    minmax.First.ValueChannel1 = Math.Min(minmax.First.ValueChannel1, sample.ValueChannel1);
    minmax.First.ValueChannel2 = Math.Min(minmax.First.ValueChannel2, sample.ValueChannel2);

    minmax.Second.ValueChannel1 = Math.Max(minmax.Second.ValueChannel1, sample.ValueChannel1);
    minmax.Second.ValueChannel2 = Math.Max(minmax.Second.ValueChannel2, sample.ValueChannel2);
  });

Console.Out.WriteLine("Channel 1 Min = {0}, Channel 1 Max = {1}, Channel 2 Min = {2}, Channel 2 Max = {3}",
minMax.First.ValueChannel1,
minMax.Second.ValueChannel1,
minMax.First.ValueChannel2,
minMax.Second.ValueChannel2);
```

Might be nicer to read (might be not, depending on whether you like functional style thinking), but it will be definitely slower than using a simple foreach loop with 4 variables (due to lots of function calls). Nice thing about this approach is that it does not use any external variables (but then you can encapsulate the foreach loop in a method).

Comment: Thanks for that input - even if it is not the best soltuion here I possibly can use that logic somewhere else in the future, so it is saved as "good to know"...

Answer (score 0):

That's an old one, but i'll share my implementation as it generic and (i think) efficient :

```
public static (T min, T max) GetMinMax<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection) where T : IComparable, new()
    {
        var min = collection.First();
        var max = collection.First();
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            if (counter == 0)
            {
                counter++;
                continue;
            }
            if (item.CompareTo(max) > 0) // item > max
                max = item;
            if (item.CompareTo(min) < 0) // item < min
                min = item;
        }
        return (min, max);
    }
```

This makes use of linq only for the initialization, but it would be easy to make it "stand alone".
(If any one has any remarks, i'll be glad to hear it)

Comment: It is mandatory that extension methods on `IEnumerable<T>` sequences enumerate the sequence at most once. `IEnumerable<T>` sequences are typically deferred, and each enumeration might produce different results.

Comment: Humm i see, that's an interesting point.
I guess you could just remove the counter so that the whole enumerable is parse then.